# What happens to extra connections when concurrent connections exceeds the limit in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, concurrency, firebase-realtime-database, connection

In Firebase realtime database,
I am using spark free account which provides 100 concurrent connections.
Suppose if there 100 concurrent connections established and more connection requests come in.
In such a situation what happen to the extra connection requests and what can we do to other than upgrading the account to tackle such situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what happens when you reach the limit of concurrent connections (number of writes per seconds)? At that moment, the Firebase database will start to queue up the number of writes that cannot be written on the disk straight away. With other words, Firebase biulds a buffer of the pendings writes. If the write volum goes down, it will start caching up with the buffer.

Maybe your next question will be, how do i know when i reached the limit? The answer is that you need to attach a `CompletionListener`. If you'll see that the time between when you start the write operation and when it completes goes up, it means that you're buffered (queued).

Comment: Thank you Alex, your answer clarified my doubt.